# Incoming Cname does not show the subdomain

Tags: subdomain

I have a subdomain:

sub.domain-one.com which has a CNAME which points to sub.domain-two.com.
All good. But when I enter sub.domain-one.com I don't see the sub.domain-two.com, but the basic page of the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How long ago did you make the change to the `sub.domain-one.com` CNAME record? It's possible that the change hasn't propogated yet.

Comment: It was around 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sub.domain-two.com must be exist on http (?) server as separate host in any form. Only CNAME don't answer on all questions

Comment: sub.domain-two.com does exist as a separate host on a http server. I can visit that site when i enter it's address. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Damn! I must wrote *sub.domain-one.com*, not two...  Because client sent "Host: sub.domain-one.com" in http-request. If you want to show two, when one requested, you have to have some different tricks (ServerAlias or Redirect, TBT!!!)