# CNAME cross subdomain mapping problem

Tags: subdomain, cname

I have the exact [same problem as this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21194/incoming-cname-does-not-show-the-subdomain) but I don't understand the solution.

I have 2 different domain name(with different hosting/provider) domain-one.com and domain-two.com which I want sub.domain-one.com to point to sub.domain-two.com using CNAME. All have been setup and propagate correctly but now when I go to sub.domain-one.com it goes to basic page of the server. If I go directly to sub.domain-two.com the page load correctly.

I've tried to add the subdomain using Addon Domains on cPanel but the problem persist.

Answer (score 2):

A `CNAME` record will only map the IP address associated with the target. Your other server is obviously shared hosting, or it does not properly listen for sub.domain2.com and therefore can't serve any content.

You could implement a reverse proxy, or otherwise make the domain-two.com listen for sub.domain-one.com.

Comment: Can give give more information(link/tutorial) regarding the 2 possible solution that you stated? I've been looking but don't have any idea what kind of method related with it.